# Excessive zooming on Google maps page renders control to map on mobile phones

Tags: javascript, ios, css

I thought of having a fixed positioned button in my page that when clicked would scroll the user to either top or bottom of the page.
Is it possible to

a) Detect zoom level of the browser and display this button only when page is zoomed to a certain level ? (otherwise the button looks annoying )

b) Implement position: fixed on ios ? I have a button currently that has a position fixed but it really does not act as fixed on my iPhone (6) ? (Android works).

I don't want to disable zooming at all on the page as it is not a good user experience.